# Where do I find this encounter next to the exit of an underwater chute after a shipwreck caused by weather control magic?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, content-identification

I recently had a conversation with a player about an encounter from a game we played probably around 15ish years ago. The encounter was likely not from an adventure but first-party published somewhere else. The particular scene that we remembered was at an exit from an underwater chute on a small island that the players used to infiltrate some caverns. They encountered undead guarding the chute, who later got back up by casters. The casters used weather control magic to shipwreck the players prior to the encounter.

What encounter was this, and in what book do I find it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Might this have been Shatterhull Isle, from *Stormwrack* (page 180)? It's one of three example adventure locales in the final chapter of the book. *Stormwrack* was published in 2005, 16 years ago.

Shatterhull Isle is a small island featuring a covey of sea hags and their ogre minions. One of the listed ways to start the adventure is by having the hags use *control weather* to wreck the players' ship (they can also use illusions to cause ships to shatter on hidden rocks). There's an underwater tunnel that the hags use to enter their lair (separate from the main entrance), which the PCs can find and swim through with a good enough Spot or Search check. At the end of the tunnel is a zombie ogre, who "waits patiently within for intruders."

The hag's lair is riddled with more zombie ogres, and the hags have 3/day *animate dead*, so they very well might raise more zombies in the middle of a fight.